# Generate grid matrix from a map defined by polygonal obstacles

Tags: geometry, game-engine, computational-geometry

Suppose that I have a large map (say `20000x20000`) defined by a large number (`20000`) of triangle obstacles (with integer coordinates) that may overlap.

Example map:
[image]

Does exist a fast way to generate a boolean grid 20000x20000 in which the cell (i, j) is 0 if it is in the free space and 1 if it is (mostly) inside a triangle?

Comment: `20000` is above usual texture size limit so you might have to split your map into smaller resolution (like 2048,4096, 8192 or 16384 depending on your gfx and driver) "squares" render each (with GL) and than compose all into resulting map (possibly outside GL).

Comment: Are there any particular programming languages you are working on for this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way - exploit facilities of any graphic library - draw these triangles by white color onto black background using 8-bit (for 8-bit boolean type) bitmap. Thus bitmap memory will contain 0/0xFF values in needed places.

You can also use own triangle rasterization routine to fill boolean matrix.

*It seems that reverse approach - checking whether every point belongs to some triangle - should be slower even with spatial data structure for triangles*